# JUnitCore.runClasses doesn't print anything

Tags: java, junit

I have a test class that I'm trying to run from a main method with the folowing code :

```
Result r = org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(TestReader.class);
```

when I examine the Result object I can see that 5 tests have been run but nothing is printed on the screen.

Should I do something else to get an output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a very clean way of doing this, since it isn't a common thing to do. You only need to print the output if you are creating a program that can be used to run tests on the command line, and JUnitCore itself does that.

All of the options involve using classes in an internal package.

```
Result r = JUnitCore.runMain(new RealSystem(), TestReader.class.getName())
```

If you want to print to something other than `System.out`, you can create your own subclass of `org.junit.internal.JUnitSystem` and use that instead of `RealSystem`

You can also use `org.junit.internal.TextListener`. See `runMain(JUnitSystem system, String... args)` in [the JUnitCore source](http://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.java) for an example.

Comment: Can you example why, "it isn't a common thing to do". Calling runClasses is described in the cookbook. If there is another way to do it, what is it?

Comment: The only time you call `runClasses()` is if you are writing your own code to run tests. Usually you have JUnitCore be your main class, run the tests form your IDE, or use something that came built in your build system to run the tests. If you need to write a custom class to run your tests, the usual way is to use org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener`. Personally, I've been annoyed at how many times I need to do something in JUnit4 and find internal classes to be the only solution.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, you should register `TextListener` like this:

```
    JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
    junit.addListener(new TextListener(System.out));
    junit.run(TestReader.class);
```

Comment: JUnit 4.11 doesn't come with TextListener in the archive.  What do I do in that case?

Comment: The `runClasses(...)` method creates a new fresh `JUnitCore` so the listeners are lost (see [code in github](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/a832c5afe5b0e7c2590d057a1a49a344d207f8a0/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.java#L62)). That's why you should use `run()` instead.